# Finding text in a document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have documents in which I need to find the text "MM" followed by three integers and compile that into a list.  Each document has different sets of numbers, but it always follows this format.

Can I utilize a MS-Word VBA code to do something like this?  If so... how?

Comment: I tried recording a macro for the first three terms MM001,MM002,MM003.  And MS Word has created Macro that records just those three terms.  Is there some easy method to use to find and highlight all terms from MM001 to MM999 in one swoop?

Comment: hey Monuman - If i understand your question correctly, word has this functionality build right in.   I posted an answer with a picture to show you how to use it, can you see if it answers your question?   I'm pretty excited about it because i think it'll solve your problem in 1 minute or less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i have just the thing for you to highlight these patterns without macros or coding required.

use the find and replace dialog in WORD and configure it like so:
[image: Word search and replace dialog box]

The magic is this expression:

```
<MM[0-9]{3}>
```

see more syntax here:
http://www.gmayor.com/replace_using_wildcards.htm

I did it here in Word 2010 and it works perfectly.

picks up
MM123
MM232
and skips
MM2f1
MM2323

Edit: if you're trying to compile it into a separate list in addition to highlighting it in the doc, I'd suggest you save a copy of the doc as a plaintext file, then write a really simple shell script or console application to grab the strings you're looking for.

Comment: I need to be able to grab the found fields "<MM[0-9]{3}>" to be put into a list as well.

Comment: Also thank you for the link.  I read through it, it will serve me well in finding types of text... now if i can only figure out how to manipulate that text found.

Comment: actually if you configure in the image, it will highlight the text as you require.  make sure to select "use wildcard".  in the replace box,  "^&" tells WORD to use the string found in the "find" box.  to get it to highlight, put focus on the "replace with" box then click on "Format" in the bottom left, and hit "highlight".  it will find strings that match your pattern and then highlight them.  let me know if you hit trouble.

Comment: just edited the response - if you want to do that, i'd suggest you just save a copy as a plaintext file and use your tool / language of choice to parse out the results.  (so you can avoid VBA, etc).

Comment: Mark.  That is great advice.  That it exactly what I will do... I think I will avoid vba...

Answer (score 0):

do you know regular expressions? (also called regex)?

This is a way to perform searches based on varying search patterns. Very easy, as you just need to use your usual search window. Just change the search pattern according to some rules. An introduction for regex in Word is available here:

http://www.svprogramming.net/regent/documentation/Microsoft-Word-Wildcards-as-Regular-Expressions.html

Good luck!

Comment: Oh wow... I didn't realize you can use regular expression in MS-WORD!  That helps a lot actually!  = D

Comment: But now that I think about it... I suppose that would only still serve as a partial solution for me.  That may allow me to find all of the text segments... 

What I was hoping for was the ability to do something like a SQL query where I can find all the unique data and put it in an ordered list.  (Ordered and highlighted in my case)

I don't need the data to be replaced with anything.  I just need to know what is there.  So... I guess I'm back to scratching my head...

Comment: I've heard you can use Visual Basic in Word using a macro.... so I'm thinking maybe I could create a macro using visual basic to find that segment of text and put it somewhere separate in an ordered list... but again... I'm not sure how... I... would... do that...

Comment: indeed you can use vba in word. I just use it in Excel, but you have the same in Word.